# When is the ordering of public/private not a style choice?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visibility, declaration, inner-classes

So normally I follow the convention of placing my public member functions before my private attributes like

```
class SomeClass {
public:
    void amazingMethod();
private:
    int fantasticAttribute;
};
```

Since what a user (including me) wants to see first in a class is the stuff I can use. However, a recent project of mine has introduced some genuine weirdness.

```
template<typename T>
class LinkedList {
public:
    class LinkedListIterator {
    public:
        LinkedListIterator(Node* node) : node(node) {}
        LinkedListIterator& operator++() {
            if (node != nullptr) {
                node = node->next;
            }
        }
    private:
        Node* node;
    };
    LinkedListIterator begin() {
        return LinkedListIterator(head);
    }
private:
    struct Node {
        Node* next;
    };
    Node* head;
};
```

This code *doesn't compile* in Visual Studio 2015, reporting that `Node` is not defined when `LinkedListIterator` tries to use it. But what is strange is that if I flip `LinkedList` so it is declared like

```
template <typename T>
class LinkedList {
private:
    //everything that was in private before
public:
    //everything that was in public before
};
```

Everything compiles correctly! Is this just a Visual Studio quirk? I'm guessing it has to do with the fact that it is a template class but I don't know.

How do I know when I have to tearfully depart from declaring public members first (as most conventions suggest)? When does it become not just a style choice?

Comment: Makes sense to me - the type `Node` hasn't been seen yet. I'm sure a language lawyer will be along to give you chapter and verse of the standard that describes it ;-)

Comment: I don't know, but I guess you could always just go   struct Node; above the iterator declaration.  as a pointer to this struct is used as a parameter for a public function in a public class, there's no reason that line couldnt be public?

Comment: As part of solving problems, it's usually a good idea to try to disprove your hypothesis first. Your hypothesis is that it has to do with `private/public`... so just make everything `public` - you'd see that one ordering compiles but the other doesn't.

Comment: With the fact that nothing stop us from having multiple private blocks and public blocks, you may consider relaxing/generalizing the style guidelines basing on this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It has nothing do with with the access types. It has everything to do with the `LinkListIterator` trying to use a type that the compiler has not seen yet.

However, since the iterator class is only using a pointer to the `Node` type a forward declaration is sufficient. The following code adds the forward declaration and compiles just fine:

```
template<typename T>
class LinkedList {
private:
    struct Node; // Private forward declaration of the private class

public:
    class LinkedListIterator {
    public:
        LinkedListIterator(Node* node) : node(node) {}
        LinkedListIterator& operator++() {
            if (node != nullptr) {
                node = node->next;
            }
        }
    private:
        Node* node;
    };
    LinkedListIterator begin() {
        return LinkedListIterator(head);
    }
private:
    struct Node {
        Node* next;
    };
    Node* head;
};

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

[Live Example](http://ideone.com/1uj2Dm)

Answer (score 1):

It has nothing to do with public and private per se. It has to do with whether `Node` has been defined yet at the point of use.

Answer (score 0):

If you like to declare public members first, recast your definitions:

```
template<typename T>
class LinkedList {
public:
    class LinkedListIterator;
    LinkedListIterator begin();
private:
    struct Node;
    Node* head;
};

template<typename T>
struct LinkedList<T>::Node {
    Node* next;
};

template<typename T>
class LinkedList<T>::LinkedListIterator {
public:
    LinkedListIterator(Node* node);
    LinkedListIterator& operator++();
private:
    Node* node;
};

template<typename T>
LinkedList<T>::LinkedListIterator::LinkedListIterator(Node* node) : node(node) {}

template<typename T>
typename LinkedList<T>::LinkedListIterator& LinkedList<T>::LinkedListIterator::operator++() {
    if (node != nullptr) {
        node = node->next;
    }
    return *this;
}

template<typename T>
typename LinkedList<T>::LinkedListIterator LinkedList<T>::begin() {
    return LinkedListIterator(head);
}
```